# Array recursive replace based on a condition for another key?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one dynamic multidimensional-array having unknown depth. I wanted to replace a `key=>value` based on another `key=>value` condition.

E.g replace `$settings[$cient_id]`'s value when `$form_id` is `1f44537`.

```php
$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2cd5985',
    'elType' => 'section',
    'settings' => array(),
    'elements' => array (
      0 => array (
        'id' => '88063e6',
        'elType' => 'column',
        'settings' => array(),
        'elements' => array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => '1f44537',
            'elType' => 'widget',
            'settings' => array (
              'ap_google_sheet_client_id' => 'test_id',
            ),
            'elements' => array (
            ),
            'widgetType' => 'form',
          ),
        )
      ),
      1 => array (
        'id' => '7878c73',
        'elType' => 'column',
        'settings' => array(),
        'elements' => array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => '1f44537',
            'elType' => 'widget',
            'settings' => array (
              'ap_google_sheet_client_id' => 'test_id',
            ),
            'elements' => array (
            ),
            'widgetType' => 'form',
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here are my unsuccessful tries

**Try-1**

```php
public function replace_recursive( $elements, $form_id ) {
        foreach ( $elements as &$element) {

            if ( $element['id'] === $form_id ) {
                $element['settings']['ap_google_sheet_client_id'] = 'replaced';
                return $elements;
            }

            if ( ! empty( $element['elements'] ) ) {
                $elements = self::replace_recursive( $element['elements'], $form_id );

                if ( $elements ) {
                    return $elements;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Try-2**

This solved the issue. But the loop doesn't stop when found the element. It loops through all the elements.

```php
public function replace_recursive( $elements, $form_id ) {

        foreach ( $elements as &$element) {

            if ( $element['id'] === $form_id ){
                $element['settings']['ap_google_sheet_client_id'] = 'replaced';
                write_log('A');
                break;
            }

            if ( ! empty( $element['elements'] ) ) {
                self::replace_recursive( $element['elements'], $form_id );
                write_log('B');
            }
        }

        return $elements;
}
```

Value replaced but I am not getting the full array $elements. Rather than getting the child array for which the value was replaced.

**Try-3**

Facing the same issue again. The named keys that are on top of `elType=widget` are converted to numbered keys. Here is a sandbox.

https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/530fb53612dd7a2017b236f218665c0142f1e63f

Comment: Share a `var_export` of your array rather than print_r().

Comment: @nice_dev Export won't work in my case. First of all, it's a large array and secondly, it gives a parser error since I am using some external API.

Comment: "it is a large array" is not a problem, we're not asking for your full source code and complete state, but provide enough details to constitute a [mcve], which includes showing _just enough_ of your array that it gives people a true view of what you're working with. If that means only showing the first element: that's fine. One thing to remember is that ideally, you want to show code that others can run - for the problem you're describing, "an API" is irrevelant: `replace_recursive` takes two arguments, show representative code that lets folks run that function, on that representative data.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the question. I was using an API that internally uses ajax and doesn't print anything. So initially not able to var_dump or export. However now I got to know that i can also copy as var_export using xdebug. Thanks.

Comment: $settings available inside each 'elements'. Please check in little bit depth. I updated the id value.

Comment: I am doing that now. But your question is over complicated. There are a lot (A LOT) of data in that example data which are unrelated to your question. You'll get more success if you reduce the data to the essential part only. Remember that we are volunteers.

Comment: I understand that. Also, I appreciate it. Let me make it small.

Comment: @trincot made it a bit smaller. I believe haven't done any mistake while editing.

Comment: Great! So if I understand correctly the question is not about the replacement itself, but how to return the overall array, right?

Comment: @trincot That's right. Replace and return the overall array. I updated the question with try 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state, the code is replacing the value correctly. It is just that you are currently returning the value `$elements` as it is returned from the recursive call. But that is a smaller array than the overall array, so you should not bubble *that* array further up.

Instead, just inject that result in the current wrapping array at the "elements" key, and return the resulting array:

```
$data = [[
    'id' => '2cd5985',
    'elements' => [[
        'id' => '88063e6',
        'elements' => [[
            'id' => '1f44537',
            'settings' => [
                'form_name' => 'New Form',
                'form_fields' => [[
                    'custom_id' => 'name',
                    'field_label' => 'Name',
                    'placeholder' => 'Name',
                    '_id' => '948d900',
                    'field_pattern_message' => 'Please match the requested format',
                ],
                [
                    'custom_id' => 'email',
                    'field_type' => 'email',
                    'required' => 'true',
                    'field_label' => 'Email',
                    'placeholder' => 'Email',
                    '_id' => '243a095',
                    'field_pattern_message' => 'Please match the requested format',
                ]],
                'ap_google_sheet_client_id' => '',
            ],
            'elements' => [],
            'widgetType' => 'form',
        ]],
        'isInner' => false,
    ]],
    'isInner' => false,
]];

function replace_recursive( $elements, $form_id ) {
    foreach ( $elements as &$element) {
        if ( $element['id'] === $form_id ) {
            $element['settings']['ap_google_sheet_client_id'] = 'replaced';
            return $elements;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $element['elements'] ) ) {
            $subelements = replace_recursive( $element['elements'], $form_id );
            if ( $subelements ) { 
                // Inject result back into our array
                $element["elements"] = $subelements; 
                return $elements;
            }
        }
    }
}
    
$res = replace_recursive( $data, "1f44537");
var_dump($res);
```

See it with another input example [in this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e03b775f72b802848af78bf64df768590f43b3e)

In the second try, you place the `return` outside of the loop. But this means you *always* return the array. Yet, you need somehow an indication whether the replacement happened or not. It is probably better to return `null` when you didn't replace the value, and only return the full array when there was a replacement. Otherwise you have no indication when you can stop looking further.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Is it working on your side? I tried but in vain. Can you copy-paste your full code?

Comment: Awesome. That works. I inserted  `echo A` & `echo B` before each `return` statement respectively. It should print A and then B. But why it prints an extra B i.e A B B

Comment: It prints a B for every recursion level that needs to unwind. The deeper the match happens, the more B's you will see.

Comment: please check here http://www.giphy.com/gifs/Jo8404BdcYvS2hlqrR. After B is printed once, it goes to `return $elements` statement. There it should be stopped. Why it again goes to `if`. what triggers it to check the if condition again?

Comment: Please realise that when you have called the function recursively X times, you will also come back from it X times. This is normal. Each time you return, you arrive at the previous level of the recursion tree, where again you must return to climb back out of the recursion tree.

Comment: Well. I am trying hard to understand the comes back thing. As you say, it comes back each time there is a return. I hope you meant the loop comes  back. Then it should check `if ( $element['id'] === $form_id ) {` . but straightly jump back to `if ( $subelements ) {` Sorry for too much of questions.

Comment: Imagine you have not found the key yet, and you make a recursive call. In that recursive execution, you also do not find the key, and recurse again. Each time the call stack grows. All those recursive calls are pending (just before the `if`). So when eventually you do get a match, all those pending recursive calls will get a return value (from the deepest to the top). And at each level, execution will continue with the `if`. And of course, each one should exit asap, so the `if` is the right tool to make that happen.

Comment: unfortunately, the above code does not work in a full way. It does not return the original array. it removes the array keys that are above the `elType=widget`. I updated the sandbox here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/530fb53612dd7a2017b236f218665c0142f1e63f

Comment: There was a missing `["elements"]` key in the assignment. Updated the code and the link to the sandbox.

Comment: NB: I also removed my earlier addition of `$key =>`, since the reference to the `["elements"]` key makes it unnecessary.